# Do all routers really must know all routes to every router?

Tags: networking, routing

This is my complicated and long question. First let's talk about the context.

Network topology: 
(RT stands for router)
[image]

```
PC A --- RT A --- RT C --- RT B --- PC B
```

(RT C has a WAN NIC connected to "the cloud")

With this situation :

- PC A must send a packet to PC B
- Default routes direct packets to the cloud
- We haven't access to RT C's configuration
- RT C only knows how to join network A, not network B
- RT A knows about network B
- RT B knows about network A

RT C's routing table:

```
Destination NIC     Gateway
0.0.0.0     WAN     Cloud
Network A   LAN A   RT A's WAN
```

RT A's routing table:

```
Destination NIC     Gateway
0.0.0.0     WAN     LAN A
Network B   WAN     LAN A
```

RT B's routing table:

```
Destination NIC     Gateway
0.0.0.0     WAN     LAN B
Network A   WAN     LAN B
```

I would like to permit PC A and PC B to communicate, but I don't have access to RT C. Networks B and BC are new.

Can PC A send a packet to RT B's WAN NIC (which is possible) and "ask RT B to direct the packet to PC B" ?

I believe replacing RT B with a VPN server should do the trick, but I would like to know if it is possible to make it without establishing a new connection.

Comment: You say it is possible for PC A to send a packet to RT B’s WAN NIC.  How is this possible if RT A and RT B are not on the same network, and RT C doesn’t know that Network B exists?

Comment: Because of the default route of RT A if I remember well.

Comment: I don’t understand that.  You say RT A’s default route is out the `WAN` NIC to `LAN A`, which is one of RT C’s addresses.  And RT C doesn’t know that Network B exists — or even Network BC.

Comment: Well, it knows network BC, because it is a network directly connected to it.

Answer (score 1):

The gateway provided has to be on a directly-connected network segment, so this isn't generally possible without either some sort of VPN configuration or configuring RT C to be aware of all subnets it needs to route.